# Is there a way to load a YAML properties file with a list in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, properties, yaml

I´m developing a Spring Boot Web application and i need to load a YAML properties file which has a list on some fields, for example:

```
x:
   - 1
   - 2
```

But when I load the file to the Environment the list is not loaded, instead it flattens the list and loads the properties wrongly. Is there a way to load the YAML file so that the properties are loaded correctly?

Comment: What does it mean that it loads the properties wrongly? Could you please add an example?

Comment: For example, it loads something like this : ´[x:1, 2:null]´, it loads the first value correctly, but then takes the other values as keys with null values

Comment: I will refer you to @Jose Martinez in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50395985/spring-boot-read-array-from-yaml-properties-file