# Spring boot read array from YAML (properties) file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is my project structure

```
- src
    - main
        - java
            - mypackage
            - resources
                - config
                    application.yml
```

and i have this in application.yml

```
document:
    templates:
        filetypes:
            - elem1
            - elem2
            - elem3
            - elem4
    hello:
        test: "hello"
```

in my Endpoint i have the following

```
@Value("${document.templates.filetypes}")
List<String> templatesFileTypes;

@Value("${document.hello.test}")
String hello;
```

in any function i can access something like `System.out.println(hello)`  and its perfectly working
but for the fileTypes its not even compiling and i receive this error :

> Error creating bean with name 'configurationEndPoint': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'document.templates.filetypes' in value
>   "${document.templates.filetypes}"

Searched alot and every solution i could find was that pointing to the write application.yml/application.xml file, which is invalid in my case since i can read the other test String but not the array;

i tried `String[]` i tried `ArrayList<String>` but i can't get it to work

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699385/spring-boot-yaml-configuration-for-a-list-of-strings

Comment: @JoshSullivan nope

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other solution provided by @Jose Martinez would work but not really as clear as needed, because its reading `document.templates.filetypes` as a String and then splitting it into array of Strings; thus i am adding my solution to this,

1- Create new class FileTypesProperties

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "document.templates")
public class FileTypesConfig {

    private List<String> fileTypes;

    public List<String> getFileTypes() {
        return fileTypes;
    }

    public void setFileTypes(List<String> fileTypes) {
        this.fileTypes = fileTypes;
    }
}
```

2- Create service and inject the previous class

```
@Service
public class FileTypeService {
    private final List<String> fileTypes;

    @Autowired
    public FileTypeService(FileTypesConfig fileTypesConfig){
        this.fileTypes = fileTypesConfig.getFileTypes();
    }

    public List<String> getFileTypes(){
        return this.fileTypes;
    }

}
```

3- In your end point simply autowire and call the previous service

```
@RestController
public class ConfigurationEndPoint {

    @Autowired
    FileTypeService fileTypeService;
    @GetMapping("/api/filetypes")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> getDocumentTemplatesFileTypes(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(fileTypeService.getFileTypes());
    }
}
```

And then your yaml file can be a real array

```
document:
    templates:
        file-types:
            - elem1
            - elem2
            - elem3
            - elem4
```

I believe this is cleaner than splitting a String into smaller strings into an array, hope this will help out someone.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I fear I hate that this is necessary, but I really appreciate knowing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

One way is to pass the elements as delimited list.  Typically we have used comma and it works out of the box for String arrays.  To use a List, then you will need to set the delimiter using Spring SPEL format... see example below.

```
document:
    templates:
        filetypes:elem1,elem2,elem3
```

-

```
@Value("${document.templates.filetypes:}")
private String[] array;


@Value("#{'${document.templates.filetypes}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> list;

@PostConstruct
void testList(){
    list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    for (String a : array) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: i just found it one second ago xD, still going to accept it since its the correct answer

Comment: i know this works for String[] not 100% on List<String>

Comment: after testing for hours, this is returning a simple String inside my array!

Comment: this would work, but its not a "clean" solution i will add my solution as a second answer for a cleaner way

Answer (score 1):

I think this is also a valid way:

```
@Service
public class FileTypeService {
    private final List<String> fileTypes;

    public FileTypeService(Environment environment) {
        this.fileTypes = Binder.get(environment).bind("document.templates.filetypes", Bindable.listOf(String.class)).get();
    }
}
```

`Bindable.setOf` can be used if a Set is needed instead of List.

Answer (score 0):

In continuation to Jose Martinez answer above you can format the yaml as below if you have a long list of values to increase the readability
see the example below.

```
document:
    templates:
        filetypes: |-
          elem1,
          elem2,
          elem3,
          elem4
```

- 

```
@Value("${document.templates.filetypes}")
private String[] array;


@Value("#{'${document.templates.filetypes}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> list;

@PostConstruct
void testList(){
    list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    for (String a : array) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```