# yml list/array to java collection mapping is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

I have the following config and java code to map the yml config however the rest, soap and javascript properties are not getting mapped.

Tried the approach given here in accepted answer but no luck
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50410542/10644550

Spring boot version: spring-boot-2.7.0

Any help would be appreciated.

application.yml

```
bpmn:
  prop:
    rest:
    - http-rest-service
    - REST
    soap:
      - http-soap-service
      - SOAP
    javascript:
      - JAVASCRIPT
      - JS-script-worker
    test1: 1235
```

Java code:

```
package com.example.orchestration.properties;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Configuration
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bpmn.prop")
@PropertySource("application.yml")
@Setter
public class BpmnProperties {


   //@Value("${rest}")
   Set<String> rest;
    //@Value("soap")
    Set<String> soap;
   // @Value("javascript")
    Set<String> javascript;

    String test1;




    public boolean isRest(String str){
        return rest.contains(str);
    }
    public boolean isSoap(String soap){
        return this.soap.contains(soap);
    }
    public boolean isJs(String js){
        return javascript.contains(js);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println(rest);
        System.out.println("test "+test1);
    }

}
```

Comment: _"the rest, soap and javascript properties are not getting mapped correctly"_ what is happening vs. what you're expecting?

Comment: they are `null` .. to be more precise, values are not mapped

Comment: Is this your entire code? If so, you didn't initiate your sets! When you create a Object field (like your sets) in Java the default value is null. Try `Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();`. But even then they are empty and don't have any content in it, so you would have to fill them with the content from your YAML file. (use an API)

Comment: In addition you can't just print out a Set or any Object without a `toString()` method. You have to iterate through it element by element.

Comment: hey @Japhei, please try before commenting..

Comment: Do you have setters for rest and soap properties?

Comment: @DirkDeyne no setters

Comment: you need setters for ConfigurationProperties to work

Comment: @DirkDeyne Tried that too however no luck

Comment: @DirkDeyne edited question with setter.. please see `@Setter` annotation and in fact nothing is getting set for example, `test1` above.

Comment: location application.yml correct? test this via @PropertySource(value = "application.yml", ignoreResourceNotFound = false). Lombok correctly configured? test via using a normal setter.

Comment: [working demo](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/sso-yml-config)

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring Boot 2.2 you can simplify your annotations to

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bpmn.prop")
public class BpmnProperties {
```

and add

```
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.example.orchestration.properties")
```

to your main class.